# Import aar file, but has two icons

Tags: android

Now I try to import an aar([libzt](https://github.com/zerotier/libzt)) file to my android project.

But the AndroidManifest.xml of aar file contain the application.
So after I import the aar file into my project, and install it.
It will exist 2 icons after installed.

I add below line to build.gradle for import aar file:

```
implementation(name: 'libzt-android', ext: 'aar')
```

How to import aar file could I do to avoid create 2 icons?

Comment: `It will exist 2 icons after installed` that's not the *AAR probably has it's own launcher activity in the manifest. You need to override it in your manifest

Comment: I add below 2 lines to my project's AndroidManifest.xml:
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:node="replace"
Is it right?

Comment: Doesn't look right for me. I'm not sure how to override the launcher activities, but it is possible for sure, and you can find how to do that over the internet

Answer (score 1):

Well that second icon is coming because your .aar library project's AndroidManifest.xml file contains an Activity entry with following <kbd>intent-filter</kbd>

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

You need to comment it out from .aar project and then again rebuild .aar and include it and second icon will not be there.

Answer (score 0):

Your `aar` library is fine do not do any changes to it. I tried to mess with my `aar` AndroidManifest.xml and indeed i was able to fix the double icon but then the consequence is a message in the log saying that `MainActivity` is null. So next, I remove the `MainActivity.java` etc... the list could go on and on messing with the `aar`. Lesson learned here: The `aar` is fine. Instead, add this line into your `apk` app `AndroidManifest.xml`:

`<activity android:name="com.smeagol.lib.MainActivity" tools:node="remove"/>`

So i learned here one of the principles of android programming, i am sure there are more.